# MySQL sort on computed column

Tags: mysql, sorting, calculated-columns

I have a table with data as follows:

```
field1 field2 realdata
------ ------ --------
ABC    01     1A
ABC    01     2A
ABC    01     1B
ABC    01     2B
ABC    01     10B
ABC    01     11B
ABC    01     10A
ABC    01     11A
ABC    02     10B
ABC    02     1A
```

I need to have the data come out sorted by by all three fields.  The A's must be grouped together, then the B's, and in numerical sequence of course.

I created FormatRealData as a stored function which returns the RealData as:
`A-01, A-10, A-02, B-11, ... etc.`  This allows me to get the sort that I needed.

I have the following query:

```
select field1, field2, RealData, FormatRealData(RealData) as SortData
from mytable
order by field1, field2, SortData
```

Now for the problem:

The above query will be used by other developers to create reports and I don't want to leave the SortData there as it should never appear in a report, only the RealData should.  Is it possible to create the column as I am doing, sort the data and then drop that column or not return it?

Comment: Did you try putting `FormatRealData(RealData)` into the order by?

Comment: Thank you @Brian Adams.  Don't know why I didn't think of that, though I am relatively new to MySQL.  Seems so obvious now.

Comment: Awesome, I knew it worked with built-in mysql functions but wasn't sure if it was the same for stored functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT field1, field2, RealData
FROM mytable
ORDER BY field1, field2, FormatRealData(RealData)
```